# What is the best way to clear couple of tables each night at specific hour in Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, windows-server

I need to clear couple of tables every night on my db so in the morning they will be empty and ready to use for the end users.

I already wrote the query to truncate them but I'm not sure what is the best way to run it scheduled every midnight.

What is the best way to schedule such a task on windows server ?

Comment: you could use the Windows Task Scheduler.  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: If you want to empty the tables, you may want to use `TRUNCATE` instead.

Comment: is it better using the scheduler over something like pgAdmin ?

Comment: @dezso - I've edited my question to use truncate.

Comment: I prefer to use the task scheduler. PgAdmin's PgAgent is largely unnecessary, and I find task scheduler both more flexible and easier. Just invoke a `psql` job.